# Calendars linked to libraries

Tags: calendar, document, library

Is there a way to link a regular SharePoint calendar to a Document library withing the SharePoint site?

Comment: What do you mean by link? What's your end goal?

Comment: I have a business partner that wants to link certain documents within the library to certain calendar dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the calendar, add a Lookup field, which points to your document library. Then when adding and editing events you can select documents.

HTH

Comment: Glad I can help, please make sure to mark this as answered for others to benefit as well!